# A second order ODE with one initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

Let $F(x , y , y' , y'') = 0$ be the general form of the second order ODE.
I wonder whether it's possible to find a equation in this form such that knowing only one initial condition determines the unique solution.
I mean a degenerate case here in a sense that unique solution is obtained by only one initial condition. Maybe it's possible to construct an equation so that $y\equiv 0$ is the only valid solution but I didn't find anything.

Comment: $(y')^2+(y'')^2=0$ and $y^2+(y')^2+(y'')^2=0$?

Comment: @AVK Thanks. Is it possible to find an example if the equation is in the explicit form? I mean $y'' = F(x,y,y')$.

Comment: If $F$ is Lipschitz continuous, then no, this is not possible. A slightly degenerate example is $y''=\sqrt{-y^2-(y')^2}$

Comment: @AVK Would you provide a reliable source for that, please?

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem

Comment: @AVK This gives us a condition for the first order ODE not second order.

Comment: The link that I provided describes the n-dimensional case